# How can I exit Sublime Text's dual-panel view?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

My Sublime 3 Text Editor looks like this, with 2 panels and no open files. The files I open are shown only in the right part, the left remains empty even when I open multiple files.

[image: This is how Sublime looks]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

try to do this

view -> layout -> single

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'll accept your answer when I can :D.

Comment: @StavrosMichalovits thank you have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to sublime text view>layout click on single